# numpy.polyfit: How to get 1-sigma uncertainty around the estimated curve?

Tags: python, numpy

I use numpy.polyfit to fit observations. polyfit gives me the estimated coefficients of the polynomial and can also provides me the error covariance matrix of the estimated coefficients. Fine. Now, I would like to know if there is a way to estimate the +/- 1sigma uncertainty around the estimated curve.

I know MatLab can do it (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56596/finding-uncertainty-in-coefficients-from-polyfit-in-matlab) but I did not found a way to make it in python.

Answer (score 9):

If you have enough data points, you can get with the parameter `cov=True` an estimated covariance matrix from `polyfit()`. Remember that you can write a polynomial `p[0]*t**n + p[1]*t**(n-1) + ... + p[n]` as the matrix product `np.dot(tt, p)` with `tt=[t**n, tt*n-1, ..., 1]`. `t` can be either a single value or a column vector. Since this a linear equation, with the covariance matrix `C_p` of `p`, the covariance matrix of the values is `np.dot(tt, np.dot(C_p tt.T))`.

So a simple example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# sample data:
x = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0,  4.0,  5.0,  6.0])
y = np.array([0.0, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1, -0.8, -1.0, -3.0])

n = 3  # degree of polynomial
p, C_p = np.polyfit(x, y, n, cov=True)  # C_z is estimated covariance matrix

# Do the interpolation for plotting:
t = np.linspace(-0.5, 6.5, 500)
# Matrix with rows 1, t, t**2, ...:
TT = np.vstack([t**(n-i) for i in range(n+1)]).T
yi = np.dot(TT, p)  # matrix multiplication calculates the polynomial values
C_yi = np.dot(TT, np.dot(C_p, TT.T)) # C_y = TT*C_z*TT.T
sig_yi = np.sqrt(np.diag(C_yi))  # Standard deviations are sqrt of diagonal

# Do the plotting:
fg, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.set_title("Fit for Polynomial (degree {}) with $\pm1\sigma$-interval".format(n))
ax.fill_between(t, yi+sig_yi, yi-sig_yi, alpha=.25)
ax.plot(t, yi,'-')
ax.plot(x, y, 'ro')
ax.axis('tight')

fg.canvas.draw()
plt.show()
```

gives [image: Polyfit with 1-sigma intervals]

Note that calculating the complete matrix `C_yi` is computationally and memorywise not very efficient.

**Update** - on the request on @oliver-w a couple words on the methodology:

`polyfit` assumes that the parameters `x_i` are deterministic and `y_i` are uncorrelated random variables with the expected value `y_i` and identical variance `sigma`. So it is a linear estimation problem and an ordinary least squares method can be used. By determining the sample variance of the residues, `sigma` can be approximated. Based on`sigma` the covariance matrix of `pp` can be calculated as shown in the [Wikipedia article on Least Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Least_squares.2C_regression_analysis_and_statistics). That is almost the method that `polyfit()` uses: There for `sigma` the more conservative factor `S/(n-m-2)` instead of `S/(n-m)` is used.

Comment: Interesting. Would you be able to cite a source that would validate this approach? Thus far, I've seen several people using different techniques to add some kind of statistical measure to such plots, such as [this one](http://scipyscriptrepo.com/wp/?p=104) (a very common approach, but apparently also [incorrect](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/105851/68932)), but few people explain *why* it is correct and readers merely assume it is correct because it looks plausible.

Comment: Where does the effect originate, that on the edges of the plot the 'filled area' broadens? Is that an effect of the plotting or does it have to do with those being the endpoints of the data?

Comment: The estimate at given position x improves if more data points are close and worsens the further away the next data points is.