# How to duplicate a polyfit line to identify data extremities

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to somehow duplicate the polyfit line to the topmost data points and the bottom data points. The first image shows the results of the code. The 2nd image shows what Im getting at. What I really would like to achieve is to plot a line or a zone for the 10% of data lying at the extremes. Is this achievable?
Note: Im not interested in the error line. I want to identify the extremes of the range using the same slope.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import polyfit

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,size=(20, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
b, m = polyfit(df.index, df['A'], 1)
plt.scatter(df.index, df['A'])
plt.plot(df.index,b + m * df.index,'r--')
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [numpy.polyfit: How to get 1-sigma uncertainty around the estimated curve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28505008/numpy-polyfit-how-to-get-1-sigma-uncertainty-around-the-estimated-curve)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. To be honest I have no idea what is going on in that example as Im still learning. If there are no other suggestions I will try and pick it apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a robust statistical uncertainty range then follow the method in the suggested duplicate, but if you just want to duplicate the lines at a given offset that’s pretty straightforward:

```py
offset = 7.5
plt.plot(df.index, b + m * df.index - offset, 'r—')
plt.plot(df.index, b + m * df.index + offset, 'r—')
```